# Why does MoveTo() draw a line?

Tags: c#, mono, cairo

Im struggling with a problem while using Cario-sharp.

I try to draw a line from point a to point b. For that, I have to move to point a with `MoveTo()`, and then draw the line with `LineTo()`. But when I use `MoveTo()` somehow a line gets drawn. What can I do against this?

Before drawing the line, I am drawing some circles. Here is what I do:

```
        context.SetSourceRGB(0.7, 0.2, 0.0);
        context.ClosePath();
        context.MoveTo(pointA);
        context.LineTo(pointB);
        context.ClosePath();
```

According to the docs, this should be working. However there are two lines, and when I comment out `LineTo()` then theres still a line drawn.

What do I have to do, that `MoveTo()` is not drawing a line?

Comment: Why are you bothering with the `close_path`s?

Comment: It fixed parts of my problems - now with Stroke in place they're both useless

Comment: That's why I was wondering. I've never even used `close_path`.

Comment: @oldtechaa I don't even know what it does excatly, it's a bit hit and miss with cairo for me xD

Comment: Do you have [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/)? On the path page there's an (albeit difficult) explanation of `close_path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `context.Stroke()` after `context.LineTo()`

Comment: @Mafii StackOverflow in a nutshell